# referencing an object named "values" within a JSON object

Tags: javascript, object, mongoose

How do I reference an array named "values" within a JSON Object? 
It seems to think I'm referencing a method?   When I console.log it shows   "values()"
[image: object]

Here is what I see when I console.log:

```
console.log ("concatting: " + failuresData.values);
console.log("with comma:", failuresData.values);
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, _JSON_ stands for [Javascript Object Notation](http://www.json.org/), which is a _string_ representing (usually) a Javascript object. It has to be [parsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) before being used as an actual Javascript object.

Comment: *When I console.log it shows "values()"* code?

Comment: Is this a mongoose `model.find` result?

Comment: then the docs would explain why the sub document property is a function AND an array-like object.

Comment: eh, current docs don't seem to explain it at all actually.. They do however explain how to access sub documents. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: thanks @KevinB I'll give it a look.  I thought I was going nuts.

Comment: basically, calling .values() with a callback calls teh callback with the collection of subdocs... but that's not really very useful when you can already access them directly, just treat it as an array.

Answer (score -1):

It works by just calling object.values

```js
const test = {
  values: [
    {id: 1}, {id: 2}
  ]
}

console.log(test.values);
```

Comment: for some reason when its JSON from Mongodb it causes issues, and you can't reference it as expected.